# How do you use php to insert into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

So i am having trouble connecting or inserting data into my database.  i am using a form to gather information that i need.  And then i try to insert into my database.  i'm not sure what the problem is but i think i having trouble with the connection.  i am using two files to try and accomplish this.

addQuite.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AddQuote</title>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

 <body>

<h2> Add a Quote <h2>

    <form action="index.php" method="get">
        <div>
            Quote:<br>

            <textarea  rows="6" cols="60" name="quote" id="quote">

            </textarea>

            <br>

            Author: <input type="text" name="author" id="author"/> <br>

            <input class = "input2" type="submit" value="Save Quotation"/>
        </div>
    </form>
  </body>


   </html>
```

And this is my index.php file which is where i am trying to connect and insert into my database

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>Quotes</title>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

  <body>


<h1> Quotes </h1>

<form action="addQuote.html">
<input class="input1" type="submit" value="Add Quote"/>
</form>

<?php
//connet to server
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=server;dbname=quotes", "root" , "");

//check connections
if($db===false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. ");
}

//get name and quote
$name = $_GET['author'];
$quote = $_GET['quote'];

//attemp insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO quotations (name, quote, rating ) VALUES 
('$name', '$quote', 0)";

?>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: check your host name generally it is 'localhost' if you run your code in your local system.

Comment: Your current code is vulnerable to sql injections. You should make sure that this doesn't happen by preparing or escaping

Answer (score 0):

have a look in following example

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is never executed, add " $db->exec($sql); " to your code.

```
<?php
//connet to server
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=server;dbname=quotes", "root" , "");

//check connections
if($db===false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. ");
}

//get name and quote
$name = $_GET['author'];
$quote = $_GET['quote'];

//attemp insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO quotations (name, quote, rating ) VALUES 
('$name', '$quote', 0)";
$db->exec($sql);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert data into MySQL with PDO you need to use prepared statements. `exec()` **SHOULD NOT** be used for inserting data. SQL query needs to be parameterized and data passed separately.

```
<?php

//connet to server
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=server;dbname=quotes;charset=utf8mb4", "root", "", $options);

//attempt insert query execution
$db->prepare('INSERT INTO quotations(name, quote, rating ) VALUES(?,?,0)')
    ->execute([
        $_GET['author'], 
        $_GET['quote']
    ]);

?>
```

You should also enable exceptions in PDO with `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, use `utf8mb4` charset, and never use `root` without password in PHP.